# Boost C++ on Apple's M1 processor, does it install and build OK?

Tags: macos, boost, clang++, apple-m1

Presumably, by now, people have successfully installed **boost** libraries on MacOS devices with M1 processors, building in native mode.

Would anyone like to discuss their experiences with this, and if there are any particular issues which need to be handled?